# Add and remove owl carousal items when search form is submitted repeatedly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, owl-carousel

I'm using AJAX calls to get my carousal items whenever a search form is submitted by pressing Enter. I want to remove previous items and add new items to carousal when Enter is pressed.

It works well all the time except when Enter is pressed repeatedly, it doesn't remove old items just keep adding new items.

### Removing items

```
function removeResult() {
    var i = 0;

    $("#result_section").slideUp(750, function () {

        $('.result_item').each(function(){

            $(".prof-carousel").trigger('remove.owl.carousel', [i++])
            .trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');

         });

    });

}
```

### Adding items

```
$("#index_search_btn").click(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    removeResult();

    var formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('type', search_type);

    formData.append('q', search_q);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        url: "/search",
        data: formData,
        success: function (response) {

       $("#result_section").slideDown(750, function () {

           $.each(response, function (index, prof) {

               var item = '';

               item += '<div class="item carousel_ostad_item result_item">'+ 'whatever...'+'</div>';


          $('.my-carousel').owlCarousel().trigger('add.owl.carousel',[jQuery(item)]).trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');
            });

        });
    },

    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

         alert(xhr.status + " " + thrownError);

         }

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did come up with a simple solution. 
I disabled search button when it is pressed (so the form can't be submitted repeatedly) and enable it again after adding carousal items in success Ajax callback.

```
$("#index_search_btn").click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
///// disable search button /////
$("#index_search_btn").attr("disabled", true);

removeResult();

var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('type', search_type);
formData.append('q', search_q);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    url: "/search",
    data: formData,
    success: function (response) {

        $("#result_section").slideDown(750, function () {

            $.each(response, function (index, prof) {
                var item = '';
                item += '<div class="item carousel_ostad_item result_item">'+ 'whatever...'+'</div>';
                $('.my-carousel').owlCarousel().trigger('add.owl.carousel',[jQuery(item)]).trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');

                ///// enable search button /////
                $("#index_search_btn").removeAttr("disabled");
            });

        });

    }, error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status + " " + thrownError);
    }

});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably because the Ajax is async and more slow and happen something similar to:

`Enter -> Remove (old el) -> Ajax call 1 -> Enter -> Remove (nothing) -> Ajax call 2 -> Ajax callback 1 ADD -> Ajax callback 2 ADD`

I hope it's clear, I don't know how to rappresent this.

What you can do is remove old elements in `success` Ajax  callback.

```
$("#index_search_btn").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // #### Remove this...
    //removeResult();

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('type', search_type);
    formData.append('q', search_q);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        url: "/search",
        data: formData,
        success: function (response) {

            // ... and move here. ####
            removeResult();

            $("#result_section").slideDown(750, function () {

                $.each(response, function (index, prof) {
                    var item = '';
                    item += '<div class="item carousel_ostad_item result_item">'+ 'whatever...'+'</div>';
                    $('.my-carousel').owlCarousel().trigger('add.owl.carousel',[jQuery(item)]).trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');
                });

            });

        }, error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status + " " + thrownError);
        }

    });

});
```